# IE Developer Tool Not Updating Values in Real Time

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

I am trying to debug my CSS with IE Developer Tool (I usually use Chrome's) but it doesn't update the value in real time. I tried changing the color, margin's values etc, but the page stays the same, not reflecting the change in real time like Chrome's Developer Tool (I believe IE's should behave just the same).

I've tried resetting it to the default setting (using Microsoft fixit tool) but it (Dev Tool) still doesn't work. Looks like it (IE - the browser) is back to the default setting though.

I am using the latest version of IE 10 on Windows 7.

How do I fix this? I guess I can use Firebug Lite, but the IE dev tool has this "downgrade" feature - browser mode which can be very handy to work with earlier version. So if possible, I would like to keep using IE's Dev Tool.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: You're not alone. This has been bugging me for a long time now, and I'm not even sure there's a solution. The IE Developer Tool is in so many respects inferior to other, similar tools, that there's only 1 thing you can do: sit silently in a corner and cry.

Comment: Your nickname fits you ;) lol.. jk :). Well.. ironically, I feel a little better knowing it is not just me. You know, I watched a Youtube video about this Dev Tool, and the Microsoft IE's engineer said that he is a "web developer at heart". I was like "really??"

Comment: That's like a dictator stating he's in favor of democracy at heart. It might be true, but it sure doesn't show.